# Appending values to a list

Tags: css, sass

In SCSS, I am trying to write a function that takes a list whose length is between zero and three, and append default values as below to make the length invariably three, and then use it. In the example, the default value for the first, second, and third position in the list are `10`, `20`, and `30`, respectively.

```
@function foo($list){
  @if length($list) < 1 {append($list, 10)}
  @if length($list) < 2 {append($list, 20)}
  @if length($list) < 3 {append($list, 30)}
  // code follows that uses @list
}
```

But the code above returns an error like this:

```
Invalid CSS after "...pend($list, 10)": expected "{", was ";".
```

How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set it to a variable, functions like `append()` are non-destructive (ie. they don't modify the original list, they only return a new list)

```
@function foo($list){
  @if length($list) < 1 { $list: append($list, 10) }
  @if length($list) < 2 { $list: append($list, 20) }
  @if length($list) < 3 { $list: append($list, 30) }
  // code follows that uses @list
}
```